# Why is that you don't need brackets when initializing an array in the member initializer list?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization, class-constructors

For example, I have:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
private:
    int size;
    int arr[10];
public:
    Foo();
};

Foo::Foo()
    : size {0}, arr { } {
    
}

int main() {

    Foo one;

}
```

This works, but if I tried to use brackets:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
private:
    int size;
    int arr[10];
public:
    Foo();
};

Foo::Foo()
    : size {0}, arr[] { } { // error
    
}

int main() {

    Foo one;

}
```

Why is that you don't need brackets when initializing an array in the member initializer list? Is this just syntax? Is this behavior with initializing arrays found anywhere else?

Comment: And why do you think they are needed?

Comment: Because that is how you initialize arrays outside of constructor member lists. To my knowledge, you don't assign/initialize any value to arrays without the use of brackets. The only place I could think of referring to arrays without brackets is when you pass them to a function  @Evg

Comment: Square brackets are used for array **declaration** (as in `int arr[10];`) and also in array **element access** (for example, `int elem = arr[7];`). Although initialization is often done on the same line as declaration (e.g., `int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};` or just `int arr[]{1, 2, 3};`), those are two separate concepts. Square brackets are not related to initialization.

Comment: Because it's unneeded in initialization, `arr { }` initializes the elements to 0, and the 'int arr[10]` creates 10 consecutive spaces in memory for an int. Which gets executed first, 'int arr[10]` or  `arr { }`? Because the initializer comes first, but doesn't the compiler need to know how many elements to initalize to 0?  @heapunderrun

Comment: When you write `arr{}` in the member initializer list, it means that **all** elements of the array will be initialized to zeroes. How many elements there are in the array is already known because of your declaration `int arr[10];`: this means the array `arr` has ten elements. The number of elements in a (C-style) array is fixed, it cannot change. If you want dynamic arrays that can grow and allow insertion of additional elements, use `std::vector` instead of a C-style array.

Comment: Sorry for unclarity, I was more so asking which statement executes '. Does `arr { }` in the constructor member list execute first or does `int arr[10]`? From my understanding, initializers execute first, but if I `arr { }` executes first, how does the compiler know to initialize 10 elements to 0? @Evg @heapunderrun

Comment: What do you mean by the execution of `int arr[10]`? It is "executed" in the same sense at `int size;`. How does the compiler know how to initialize `size` member?

Comment: Suppose you have two simple lines of code in main, 'int x { 5 }` on line 5. On line 6, you have `int y { 6 }`.   'int x { 4 }` will execute first. Then, `int y { 5 }` will execute second. How does the program know to initialize 10 values to 0 if `arr { }` executes first because `arr { }` does not explicitly state how many elements there are in the array.  `int arr[10]` does state how many elements there. My understanding is if  `arr { }` is executed first, how does it know that there are 10 elements in the array? @Evg

Comment: You can't initialize an undeclared array. First, a compiler sees a declaration `int arr[10];`, then it initializes it with 10 zeros - when it comes to initialization, the declaration has already been seen. This order is fixed by the language rules.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! I understand now @Evg